# Lock down OSX 10.7.5 app into kiosk mode?

Tags: macos, applications

I want to run an app in 'kiosk' mode for public unattended access via touch screen (no mouse or keyboard attached). I can already automate a network user logon and then the app launches (but only in last state - not necessarily full screen - which I want) I know with Workgroup Manager you can hide the dock, use simple Finder etc...but need something more powerful. Ideally it needs to monitor if the app crashes out and restart it / log limited user off and back on again.

Thanks

Phil

Answer (score 6):

You could enable the Guest account along with Simple Finder, then write a launchctl to [watch for the front-most app and re-open it if necessary.](http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20110617204111325)

There are also a number of 3rd party products, such as [eCrisper](http://ecrisper.com/):

> eCrisper makes it easy to turn a Mac into a secure public access Internet kiosk. It is used by schools, museums, hotels, churches, and libraries to reliably and elegantly give access to web content.

[xStand](http://www.xstandapp.com/en/index.html):

> xStand allows you to setup a full internet kiosk in a public space in a couple of minutes.

Also found [this question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/14277/how-to-kiosk-mode-a-web-page-osx-chrome) which mentions both Opera and Chrome.